# What are scala's rules for resolving conflicting implicit values

Tags: scala

Given the following code:

```
/**
  * Created by danap on 12/8/15.
  */
object ImplicitTest {
  trait EC {
    override def toString : String = s"EC"
  }

  trait DEC extends EC {
    def sub : EC
    override def toString : String = s"DEC - $sub"
  }

  def usesEC(implicit ec : EC) = ec.toString

  class B(implicit val dec: DEC) {
    def whichEC = usesEC
  }

  class C(implicit val dec: DEC) {
    implicit val _ec = dec.sub

    def whichEC = usesEC
    def whichECExplicit = usesEC(_ec)
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val dec : DEC = new DEC {
      val sub = new EC {}
    }

    val b = new B
    val c = new C

    println(s"b class = ${b.whichEC}")
    println(s"c class = ${c.whichEC}")
    println(s"c class = ${c.whichECExplicit}")
  }
}
```

The output for scala 2.11 is:

```
b class = DEC - EC
c class = DEC - EC
c class = EC
```

I expected it to be:

```
b class = DEC - EC
c class = EC
c class = EC
```

Because the implicit val `_ec` is declared "closer" to the call to `usesEC` in `whichEC`.  Why does this happen?  Also,how I might be able to force `_ec` to be used implicitly in `C.whichEC`?

Comment: Personal rule #1 when using implicits in scala: never have in scope more than one of the same type because you never know who is overriding who.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub-type wins:

```
class Super             { override def toString = "Super" }
class Sub extends Super { override def toString = "Sub"   }

// does not compile - ambiguous
object Test1 {
  implicit val s1 = new Super
  implicit val s2 = new Super

  println(implicitly[Super])
}

// does not compile - ambiguous
object Test2 {
  implicit val s1 = new Sub
  implicit val s2 = new Sub

  println(implicitly[Super])
}

object Test3 {
  implicit val s1 = new Super
  implicit val s2 = new Sub

  println(implicitly[Super])
}

Test3 // 'Sub'
```

The rules for resolution of implicit parameters are defined in [§7.2 of the Scala Language Specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html):

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules of static overloading resolution.

This links to §6.26.3 which deals with type inference. Here a type `A <: B` gives the alternative sub-class `A` a relative weight of `1` over the alternative super-class `B`, making `A` *more specific* than `B`.

---

In general, as the comment suggests, you should avoid bringing multiple unqualified members (prefix-less, i.e. implicit values that are found in default locations for example through companion objects) into scope.