# Implicit resolution choosing the most specific subtype

Tags: scala, implicit, subtype, scalac

Can some one explain me why scala resolve the most generic implicit no matter of local scope implicit more specific ?

Example:

```
import scala.math.ScalaNumber

type Serializer[T] = T => String

object SerializedOps{
  implicit class AnyOps[T](t: T){
    def serialize(implicit s: Serializer[T]) : String = s(t)
  }
}

object Instances{
  implicit val scalaNumber : Serializer[ScalaNumber] = _.toString + "_DEFAULT"
}


import SerializedOps._
import Instances._


implicit val bigDecimalCustom : Serializer[BigDecimal] = _.toString + "_CUSTOM"

val res: String = BigDecimal(100).serialize
//res: String = 100DEFAULT
```

Why i can't define a new implicit more specific in my local scope? How scala resolve implicits ?

Comment: Take a look to the [**implicits priority guideline**](https://typelevel.org/cats/guidelines.html) - And [**where does scala look for implicits**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Subtype does win](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34180260/5205022):

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter's type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules
>   of static overloading resolution.

however function is [contravariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html#other-examples) over its argument type which makes

```
ScalaNumber => String
```

a subtype of

```
BigDecimal => String
```

thus `ScalaNumber => String` is more specific. Note that `type Serializer[T] = T => String` is aliasing a function type.

Comment: Now it’s clear, but there is a way to do what i need ? Define a generic Serializer and define a more specific one in local scope ?